# array loading issue

Tags: c, arrays

```
  printf("Please enter the start date of your trip Month/Day/Year seperated by a space:");
      scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &day, &year);
      checkC = error_date(month,day,year);
      if (checkC == 2)
        {
          travel_month[i][0] == month;
          travel_day[i][0] == day;
          travel_year[i][0] == year;
        }
      else
        while (checkC==1)
          {
            printf("Please enter the start date of your trip Month/Day/Year seperated by a space:");
            scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &day, &year);
            checkC= error_date(month,day,year);
          }
  for (row = 0; row < trip_num; row++)
    {
      for (col=0; col < DEST; col++)
       printf("Trip#:%d %d/%d/%d\n", row+1, travel_month[row][col], travel_day[row][col], travel_year[row][col]);
    }

  return 0;
}



int error_date(int month, int day, int year)
{
  int checkC;
  if ( ((month > 0) && (month <= 12)) &&  ((day > 0) && (day <= 31)) && ((year> 2000) && (year < 2050)) )
    {
      checkC = 2;
      return checkC;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Invalid date please re-enter date\n");
      checkC = 1;
      return checkC;
    }
}
```

Am I loading the month/day/year wrong, I keep getting weird integers when I'm printing out the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use single equals sign for assignment:

```
      travel_month[i][0] == month;
      travel_day[i][0] == day;
      travel_year[i][0] == year;
```

should be

```
      travel_month[i][0] = month;
      travel_day[i][0] = day;
      travel_year[i][0] = year;
```